# Is it possible to use generic Consumer as function argument in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

Code:

```
public void ifChangedString(String key, Consumer<String> consumer) {
    ...
    consumer.accept(getString(key));
}

public void ifChangedBoolean(String key, Consumer<Boolean> consumer) {
    ...
    consumer.accept(getBoolean(key));
}
```

Is it possible to make single method like `public <T> void ifChanged(String key, Class<T> clazz, Consumer<T> consumer)`?

Well obvious solution is `public void ifChanged(String key, Consumer<Object> consumer)` but I don't want to use `Object` as argument type, better to use several methods like above.

The problem is that for `accept` method I need `? super XXX` and only super is Object. So is it possible at all?

Comment: Are `String` and `Boolean` the only options, or do you have some other methods in addition to `getString()` and `getBoolean()`? If `String` and `Boolean` are the only options, do you want a solution which enforces this at compile-time, or would a runtime check (throwing `IllegalArgumentException` when called with the wrong `clazz`) be sufficient?

Comment: What are you using the `String key` for?

Comment: @Scratte updated code.

Answer (score 2):

You can create generic method that accepts type `T` object and `Consumer` of type `T`

```
public <T> void ifChanged(T t, Consumer<T> consumer) {

    consumer.accept(t);

}
```

And you can call that method by passing any object with corresponding `Consumer` action

```
ifChanged("String", s->System.out.println(s.length()));
ifChanged(10, i->System.out.println(i.toString()));
```

Comment: It's String key, not T value. I imagine the OP also needs `getValue(key) as T` to pass into the consumer.

Comment: It works only if method `accept` accepts function argument. And here I need to assign some value to `T` and it's impossible until `T` is super of whatever. I've updated my code. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: sorry it is not really clear to me @Drunya so your are looking to make dynamic decision call of  `getBoolean()` or `getString()` based on consumer type ?

Comment: @Deadpool yes and consumer should then accept this type and not `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

In essence, you just break nested if/else condition checking into several methods. Why not change both the consumer and the supplier.

```
public <T> void ifChangedT(String key, Consumer<T> consumer, Supplier<T> supp) {
    ...
    consumer.accept(supp.get());
}
```

It's an example of Premature optimization in my opinion. Sometimes by leaving the nested if/else it is, you can get a simple and clear code style, although coupled.

Comment: Of course :) It's so simple when seen, but hard to find when you're already down the wrong path. You may increase upvotes if you package it in a small compilable & runnable proof of concept.

Comment: good thought, just that it lacked the usage of `key` as in the original question and could have made [use of a `Function<String, T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59914201/1746118) instead of that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Given the current code in question and close to what is mentioned in [sully's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59911395/1746118), you can make use of a `Function` defined along with the generic `Consumer` to get the value to consume:

```
public static <T> void ifChangedGeneric(String key, Consumer<T> consumer, Function<String, T> function) {
    consumer.accept(function.apply(key));
}
```

The implementation could be further used as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ifChangedGeneric("key", <Class>::useString, <Class>::getString);
    ifChangedGeneric("true", <Class>::useBoolean, <Class>::getBoolean);
}
```

---

With a sample implementation of the `getBoolean/String` and `useBoolean/String` methods as follows...

```
static Boolean getBoolean(String key) {
    return key.equalsIgnoreCase("true") ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
}

static void useBoolean(Boolean bool) {
    System.out.println("Boolean implementation!");
    System.out.println(bool.equals(Boolean.TRUE));
}

static String getString(String key) {
    return key + ": naman";
}

static void useString(String str) {
    System.out.println("String implementation!");
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

The output generated would be:

> ```
> String implementation!
> key: naman
> Boolean implementation!
> true
> ```